# Routing to controller with a second parameter that's not an id in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

1) I have a controller with a prefix route i.e. Companies.

When I call the following action:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCompanies(...
{
    ...
}
```

it returns me the list of companies but now I'd like to declare a second action where I can return a list of companies and its top 3 contacts, so I thought I'd define my new action with the following route as such:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Contacts")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCompaniesAndContacts(...
{
    ...
}
```

As the `RoutePrefix` is defined as

```
[RoutePrefix("Companies")]
```

I thought I'd be able to call my uri using the following:

```
http://localhost/companies/contacts
```

but that always seems to be hitting the GetCompanies action.

I can only assume that my route is not being handled but I'm not sure how would I add such a specifc action to

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(....)
```

2) Also, is the way to define this second route rest compliant or is it better to use a query string parameter to indicate I want to include the users?

../companies
../companies/users

Thanks

**UPDATE-1:**

This is what my Register function in my WebApiConfig.cs has and tried to add a specific route but no luck:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "OrganizationWithUsers",
    routeTemplate: "api/Companies/Contacts"
);
```

**UPDATE-2:**

If I remove:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCompanies(...
{
    ...
}
```

It calls

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Contacts")
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCompaniesAndContacts(...
{
    ...
}
```

but I get the error `The value 'contacts' is not valid for Guid.`.

Hmmm... I can see what's happening but I'm not sure how to fix it. I also have a GetCompany which is defined as followed:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCompany(Guid id)
```

so it looks like this one is being hit now, which make sense.

I tried to add a constraint on this one and add my route back to GetCompaniesAndContacts and remove the RoutePrefix but it didn't work.

I think there is a conflict because I've got 2 identical gets and it can't differentiate between the 2.

**UPDATE-3:**

Here's the full definition as requested:

```
[RoutePrefix("Companies")]
[ValidationModel]
[ApiException]
public class CompaniesController : BaseController
{
    ...
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCompanies(
        int pageIndex,
        int pageSize,
        string orderBy,
        OrderByDirection orderByDirection,
        string filters)
    {
       ...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Contacts")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCompaniesAndContacts(
        int pageIndex,
        int pageSize,
        string orderBy,
        OrderByDirection orderByDirection,
        string filters)
    {
       ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add a [Route("Test")] to your first action? It should work like what you are trying, like this - https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/10/web-api-2-controller-with-multiple-get-methods/

Comment: Just tried it and I get: "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."

Comment: Is the attribute routing [enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) ? Usually it's done by this call - `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()`

Comment: @Fabjan I have. I've updated my answer to show this. I've also added a new specific route but to no avail.

Comment: Did you try with this [Route("Companies/Contacts")]

Comment: Why not add it to HttpGet? [HttpGet("/contacts")]

Comment: Why did you hardcode the route template 'api/Companies/Contacts' ? Effectively it means that it'll send all requests to that api. Try deleting this template at all and it should do the trick

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee I tried that but somehow it is still picking up the "Companies" rather that "Companies/Contacts"

Comment: @Fabjan As I couldn't get to work with the above so I thought I'd tried this the route but it didn't work either. Long gone :)

Comment: Does it work now ?

Comment: @Fabjan nope, unfortunately

Comment: I think since there is no route added to GetComapnies it is always defaulting to Companies , can you add a route [Route("companies"] and try it out

Comment: It's difficult to say something having that little information. All I can say now is: It should work, I've just created a simple webapi app with 1 controller and 2 functions and it worked as expected...

Comment: @Thierry can you also add your controller declaration and attributes used.

Comment: @Yasser I've just added it in UPDATE-3

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new project, I was able to create a new controller, write 2 GET actions

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public string GetCompanies()
    {
        return "Companies";
    }

    public string GetCompaniesAndContacts()
    {
        return "Companies & Contacts";
    }
}
```

The following 2 URLs work as expected

- http://localhost:5000/test/GetCompanies
- http://localhost:5000/test/GetCompaniesAndContacts

WITHOUT any change to routes.

Now I see you are trying to set a particular route pattern, so I changed my code to this...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Company Routes",
    url: "api/Companies/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Test", action = "GetCompanies", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

I added the above route before the default route and then the following URL worked as expected

- http://localhost:5000/api/companies/
- http://localhost:5000/api/companies/GetCompaniesAndContacts

I would suggest you play with routing on a NEW scratch project and then apply the understanding to your use-case.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll keep staring at your code until I spot a difference :).

Comment: I see that you are using the action as part of the route but what if it name you want to use is not the action name? In my case, my route is "companies/users" but my action is called GetCompaniesAndUsers which I don't want to use, nor do I want to rename my action name.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem and it was down to the route prefix!

I had it defined as:

```
[RoutePrefix("companies")]
public class CompaniesController : BaseController
{
}
```

When it should have been defined as:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/companies")]
public class CompaniesController : BaseController
{
}
```

Once defined as the above, I was able to use

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCompanies(
    int pageIndex,
    int pageSize,
    string orderBy,
    OrderByDirection orderByDirection,
    string filters)
{
...
}
```

to request companies only using

```
http://localhost/api/companies?PageIndex...
```

and to request the companies and main contacts, I just had to defined the new route with "Contacts".

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Contacts")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCompaniesAndContacts(
    int pageIndex,
    int pageSize,
    string orderBy,
    OrderByDirection orderByDirection,
    string filters)
{
...
}
```

And I'm now able to call it as follows:

```
http://localhost/api/companies/contacts?PageIndex...
```

**Silly mistake** but still hope this helps others. Don't forget to include your `api` in the prefix route!!